# Same height of boxes works just after refresh

Tags: jquery, css, height, refresh, box

I Used This Script for Same Boxes Height

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.box').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.box').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```

But actually It works a bit strange. First It loads data from Database and after that it should do that but it does not so I need to refresh the page to get the effect I used it in the header as same as in the footer. Without change any Advices what i did bad ?
Page is matus-satara.com You can check it live :)

Comment: Have you check the flexbox to do it with css ? Check this : http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback

Comment: I do not have time to redo it to flexboxes but In next Project I ll make them in that way you saying thank you for post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have both a `src` AND actual content in the same script tag.

Separate the scripts like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.box').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.box').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I just pasted it bad :-) check the site it is okey i think

Comment: Actually I did not noticed that you added another script :) It is correct one way what you need to do it place that at the bottom of the site under everything in footer works for me :)

Comment: I think the behavior you're describing depends on many factors (such as caching for example), but the important thing was to have a correct HTML syntax.

Comment: it was because I had it in the content that means after the first load script did nothing because page was not loaded. Next refresh was page loaded so it executed the script :) as I said I had to move it really at the bottom of the site and it works thx for that you fixed my misstake :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE9, give the parent container the style `display: flex` which will make all children grow to the same height. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox